# Subtract Single Cell Value from Column Until Empty Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to 'normalize' a column of data by setting the minimum value to 0 and shifting the entire column's data by the difference of the min value and 0.

The code should be simple, but I can't find the appropriate range selection to stop the code when it reaches a blank cell.

Below is the core that I've unsuccessfully been working off of trying to recognize the first empty cell in column U after U9 up to U700 and correspondingly stop subtracting in column Z. Example screenshots are attached. Thank you!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

[Z9:Z700] = [U9:U700-U8]

End Sub
```

This is what I get:

[image: This is what I get]

This is what I would like to get:

[image: This is what I would like to get]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim lRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        lRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("U9:U" & lRow).Copy .Range("Z9")
        With .Range("U8")
            .Formula = "=MIN(U9:U" & lRow & ")"
            .Copy
        End With
        .Range("Z9:Z" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlSubtract
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

If you have formulas in Column U, below your list of numbers, which are returning blank values, then this revision might work better for you:

```
Sub foo2()
    Dim lRows As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        lRows = WorksheetFunction.Count(.Range("U9:U700"))
        .Range("U8").Formula = "=MIN(" & .Range("U9").Resize(lRows, 1).Address(0, 0) & ")"
        .Range("U9").Resize(lRows, 1).Copy
        .Range("Z9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        .Range("U8").Copy
        .Range("Z9").Resize(lRows, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlSubtract
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Olly for your reply. This code seems to have no effect. Is there something I missed?

Comment: I have no idea what you might have missed. Have you tried stepping through it (pressing F8) ?

Comment: Stepping through the code, it works but is still pasting beyond the blank cell in column U all the way to Z700. Essentially what picture 1 depicts above.

Comment: Did you pick up on the edit I made, about a minute after posting?

Comment: I've added another version, in case your blank cells below your data range in Column U are actually formulas returning blank values.

Comment: I'm not sure about the edit, but Sub foo2() works perfectly. Thank you so much for your help!